# Using .env.local file for API Credentials to connect to my Airtable DB

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

This is my very first time using a .env file and I'm in the process of learning Next.js.

I have tried reading the Next.js docs and searching online but I hear they updated Next.js recently and everything changed and I'll admit I am currently way out of my depth.

Here's my .env.local file (changed api details for obvious reasons)

```
# .env
DB_URL=https://api.airtable.com/v0/
DB_APPID=app1234567890
DB_TABLE=Table%1234567890
DB_KEY=key1234567890
```

Here's my create.js page:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Router, { withRouter } from 'next/router'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const db = await myDB.connect({
    AirBaseUrl: process.env.DB_URL,
    AirAppId: process.env.DB_APPID,
    AirTable: process.env.DB_TABLE,
    AirKey: process.env.DB_KEY,
  })
}

const Create = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [body, setBody] = useState('');
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('mario');


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const blog = { title, body, author };

    fetch(AirBaseUrl + AirAppId + "/" + AirTable, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + AirKey,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: {
        "records": [
          {
            "fields": {
              "Notes": "Notes posted here",
              "Company Name": "Joe Blogs"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(blog)
    }).then(() => {
      // history.go(-1);
      Router.push({
        pathname: '/'
      })
    })
  }

  const getAirtable = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const blog = { title, body, author };

    fetch(AirBaseUrl + AirAppId + "/" + AirTable, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + AirKey,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(blog)
    }).then(() => {
      // history.go(-1);
      Router.push({
        pathname: '/'
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="create">
      <h2>Add a New Blog</h2>
      <div>Airtable info to be posted here</div>
      <button onClick={getAirtable}>Get Airtable Data</button>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Blog title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Blog body:</label>
        <textarea
          required
          value={body}
          onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <label>Blog author:</label>
        <select
          value={author}
          onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="mario">mario</option>
          <option value="yoshi">yoshi</option>
        </select>
        <button>Add Blog</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Create;
```

I'm currently getting an error: `myDB is not defined`

I also can't workout how to use the credentials from .env.local

I have copied this text from the docs:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const db = await myDB.connect({
    AirBaseUrl: process.env.DB_URL,
    AirAppId: process.env.DB_APPID,
    AirTable: process.env.DB_TABLE,
    AirKey: process.env.DB_KEY,
  })
}
```

But I'm not sure where myDB should be sense my error.

Finally, you'll notice in the code I have a GET function and a POST function, when you click the button, it should post the GET info in the div but I can't quite workout who I would go about that. The POST function should post details to the Airtable DB when it's click. I've just added dummy info for now.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how I get over the finish line?

Comment: Do you have the database set up? You'll need to define `myDB` with your database client.

Answer (score 0):

In order to surface the environment variables from a `.env` file, you can use something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). This allows you to load environment variables from a `.env` file that you specify.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env.local' })
console.log(process.env.FOO)
```

If your `.env` is in the root of your project (and just named `.env`) then you don't need to pass in the path config

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: I get the following error adding that line. ./pages/create.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dotenv'
  1 | import { useState } from "react";
  2 | import Router, { withRouter } from 'next/router'
> 3 | require('dotenv').config()

Comment: You will need to add `dotenv` to your `package.json` https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#install